# Is this warning about wireless modules interfering with aircraft systems true?

Tags: interference, modem, cellular

I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX6bX.png) the following warning for Sierra wireless (cellular) modems:

> Do not operate the Sierra Wireless modem in any aircraft, whether the aircraft is on the ground or in flight. In aircraft, the Sierra Wireless modem **MUST BE POWERED OFF**. When operating, the Sierra Wireless modem can transmit signals that could interfere with various onboard systems.
>
> *Note: Some airlines may permit the use of cellular phones while the aircraft is on the ground and the door is open. Sierra Wireless modems may be used at this time.*

However, from what I know, the restriction on cellular communication in aircraft is (was?) an FCC regulation, not an FAA regulation–presumably because it causes trouble for cell towers on the *ground*, not for the aircraft itself.

And that makes sense: people forget to turn off their phones all the time, so it would make no sense for aircraft designers not to account for this.

Nevertheless, this warning is explicitly saying otherwise.

I was wondering, how true is this warning actually? Could such a modem really interfere with aircraft equipment, and could this actually be *airline*-dependent? Is there any history of this happening?

Comment: IIRC there's an FCC restriction *and* an FAA restriction.

Comment: @immibis: Huh? [*"Contrary to popular misconception, the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) does not actually prohibit the use of personal electronic devices (including cell phones) on aircraft."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft)

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phones_on_aircraft

> In the U.S., Federal Communications Commission (FCC) regulations
> prohibit the use of mobile phones aboard aircraft in flight.[1]
> Contrary to popular misconception, the Federal Aviation Administration
> (FAA) does not actually prohibit the use of personal electronic
> devices (including cell phones) on aircraft.
>
> Paragraph (b)(5) of 14
> CFR 91.21 leaves it up to the airlines to determine if devices can be
> used in flight, allowing use of "Any other portable electronic device
> that the operator of the aircraft has determined will not cause
> interference with the navigation or communication system of the
> aircraft on which it is to be used."

With the use of Wi-Fi on some flights the use of cell phones is permitted, through a Wi-Fi link. It would seem that the FCC has not relaxed its regulations as far as cell tower links by plane.

The issue is that planes move so fast that tower to tower hops would be continuous. With thousands of planes in the air the cell towers could be overloaded and drop calls.

However the use of a dedicated LAN Wi-Fi and low emission electronics had led to the airlines having the final say about cell-phone use and laptops. Ancient planes like the 727 could not block noisy devices on the plane, which affected cockpit instruments. Todays jet planes are much better shielded, and may offer a in-flight phone and local Wi-Fi, through controlled data pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Cellular phones can generate electric fields of up to 30 V/m. These can disrupt many electronic devices, including avionics. There have been  a few incidents of the instruments going crazy during a landing. The manufacturer of the module wants to stress this, that they don't in any way contribute to an accident.

More modern planes, say post-1990, are designed to be safe against this level of electric field. Some airlines allow you to use your phone all the time on board. The manufacturer doesn't know that it'll be on a new plane..

There's a separate discussion about interference with the ground network if you're high up, and/or moving fast, but that's not what they're worried about.